# Is really possible to use the caches in Cortex-A7 after disabling ACTLR.SMP bit?

Tags: arm, cortex-a

As per the MPCORE manual enabling SMP bit enables cache coherency. But that is related to multi-core system. I do not want cache coherency to be enabled in my system. Then with disabling SMP bit will I be able to use caches?

Answer (score 0):

If you set SMP=0 and mark the pages as cacheable and sharable in the Page Tables then all such pages will be treated as uncached because that would be the only way to ensure sharability in the absence of cache coherency (SMP=0).

So the key is to mark the pages as only cachable and not sharable when SMP=0